# Countdown is working on first button only but not on other buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need your help. I have got a download button with a countdown but there is an issue with the button. It only works on First Button or if when clicked on 2nd button first, the starts on 1st button instead of 2nd button. Please help me to fix this error.
I have created a snippet with the coding. Please review it and let me know, what is wrong! Thank you.

```js
  function generate() {
    var e, n = document.getElementById("downloadingx"),
      t = document.getElementById("downloadbuttonx"),
      a = document.getElementById("downloadingx").href,
      l = 10,
      d = document.createElement("span");
    n.parentNode.replaceChild(d, n), e = setInterval(function() {
      --l < 0 ? (d.parentNode.replaceChild(n, d), clearInterval(e), window.open(a), n.style.display = "inline") : (d.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-clock-o' aria-hidden='true'/> Redirecting to download page in " + l.toString() + " seconds.", t.style.display = "none")
    }, 1e3)
  }
```

```css
#downloadbuttonx{
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #e67e22;
  float: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}

#downloadbuttonx:hover,
#downloadingx:hover{
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #b62727;
  outline: none;
}

.batas-downx{
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display:block;
}

.background-box-st{
  background: #b62727;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  width: 310px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius:5px;
  border-top-left-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.background-box-n{
  background: #a30085;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  width: 310px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius:5px;
  border-top-left-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.file-name{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.catatan-downx{
padding:20px;
background:#f7f7f7;
color:#555;
font-size:20px;
}

#downloadingx{
  display:block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #e67e22;
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  text-align:center;
  float:none;
  line-height:80px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.bungkus-info span{
display:block;
line-height:80px;
float:none;
}

.file-deskripsi{
display:block;
}

.file-deskripsi span{
margin-right:3px;
}

#downloadbuttonx,
a#downloadingx{
width:160px;
padding:15px;
cursor:pointer;
}

.bungkus-info span{
float:none;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}

.file-deskripsi{text-align:center}
}
```

```html
<div class="batas-downx">
  <div class="background-box-n">
    <div class="bungkus-info">
      <div class="file-name">File 1</div>
      <button id="downloadbuttonx" onclick="generate()"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download</button>
      <a href="#" id="downloadingx" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Redirecting...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="batas-downx">
  <div class="background-box-st">
    <div class="bungkus-info">
      <div class="file-name">File 1</div>
      <button id="downloadbuttonx" onclick="generate()"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download</button>
      <a href="#" id="downloadingx" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Redirecting...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you cannot have the same ID, i.e ``downloadingx`` for two different elements. Both your **button**'s have the same ID, thus the javascript targeting the first ID every time you press the second button.

Comment: Hey @NotABot! Then what should I use? What would be the code?

Comment: @NotABot! Can you please create a snippet with the Solution. Please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function generate(buttonId,hrefId) {
    var e, n = document.getElementById(hrefId),
      t = document.getElementById(buttonId),
      a = document.getElementById(hrefId).href,
      l = 10,
      d = document.createElement("span");
    n.parentNode.replaceChild(d, n), e = setInterval(function() {
      --l < 0 ? (d.parentNode.replaceChild(n, d), clearInterval(e), window.open(a), n.style.display = "inline") : (d.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-clock-o' aria-hidden='true'/> Redirecting to download page in " + l.toString() + " seconds.", t.style.display = "none")
    }, 1e3)
  }


<div class="batas-downx">
      <div class="background-box-n">
        <div class="bungkus-info">
          <div class="file-name">File 1</div>
          <button id="downloadbuttonx0" onclick="generate('downloadbuttonx0','downloadingx0')"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download</button>
          <a href="#" id="downloadingx0" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Redirecting...</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="batas-downx">
      <div class="background-box-st">
        <div class="bungkus-info">
          <div class="file-name">File 1</div>
          <button id="downloadbuttonx1" onclick="generate('downloadbuttonx1','downloadingx1')"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download</button>
          <a href="#" id="downloadingx1" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Redirecting...</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The Perfect One  Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to pass the **ID** of the button using `this.id`, and then using that ID to get which button is clicked.

See the below example.

```js
function generate(idOfButtonClicked){
 console.log("ID is: ", idOfButtonClicked)
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-1" onclick="generate(this.id)"> Click Me</button>
<br />

<button id="btn-2" onclick="generate(this.id)"> Click Me</button>
```

Now coming to your code, you can pass the **id** as the parameters to the `generate()` function.
Also, have to have some id `downloadingx` for each of the `<a>` tag, you can have something like this as id for each `downloadingx-btn-download-1` and `downloadingx-btn-download-2` respectively.

The thing is that you cannot have the same ID for different elements on a page.

```js
  function generate(btnId) {
    var e, n = document.getElementById(btnId),
      t = document.getElementById(btnId),
      a = document.getElementById("downloadingx-"+btnId).href,
      l = 10,
      d = document.createElement("span");
    n.parentNode.replaceChild(d, n), e = setInterval(function() {
      --l < 0 ? (d.parentNode.replaceChild(n, d), clearInterval(e), window.open(a), n.style.display = "inline") : (d.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-clock-o' aria-hidden='true'/> Redirecting to download page in " + l.toString() + " seconds.", t.style.display = "none")
    }, 1e3)
  }
```

```css
#downloadbuttonx{
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #e67e22;
  float: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}

#downloadbuttonx:hover,
#downloadingx:hover{
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #b62727;
  outline: none;
}

.batas-downx{
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display:block;
}

.background-box-st{
  background: #b62727;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  width: 310px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius:5px;
  border-top-left-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.background-box-n{
  background: #a30085;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  width: 310px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius:5px;
  border-top-left-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.file-name{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.catatan-downx{
padding:20px;
background:#f7f7f7;
color:#555;
font-size:20px;
}

#downloadingx{
  display:block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #e67e22;
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  text-align:center;
  float:none;
  line-height:80px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.bungkus-info span{
display:block;
line-height:80px;
float:none;
}

.file-deskripsi{
display:block;
}

.file-deskripsi span{
margin-right:3px;
}

#downloadbuttonx,
a#downloadingx{
width:160px;
padding:15px;
cursor:pointer;
}

.bungkus-info span{
float:none;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}

.file-deskripsi{text-align:center}
}
```

```html
<div class="batas-downx">
  <div class="background-box-n">
    <div class="bungkus-info">
      <div class="file-name">File 1</div>
      <button id="btn-download-1" onclick="generate(this.id)"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download</button>
      <a href="#" id="downloadingx-btn-download-1" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Redirecting...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="batas-downx">
  <div class="background-box-st">
    <div class="bungkus-info">
      <div class="file-name">File 2</div>
      <button id="btn-download-2" onclick="generate(this.id)"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download</button>
      <a href="#" id="downloadingx-btn-download-2" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Redirecting...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you can add css class like .download_btn so that you can reduce css code. I am sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Hey @Not A Bot, Your solution is working fine for me but there are two minor issues. 
1: When I click on 'Download' the size of the button reduces till File title and then get back to the orignal size when the timer begins. Whereas the size should remain the same.

2: When time-lapse, 'Redirecting...' should appear whereas, Download button appearing again.

Are there any ways to fix these issues?

Answer (score 2):

You should really register your event listeners in JavaScript. Doing so will let you use `this` inside `generate` to refer to the element to which the event listener was bound.

From there it's trivial to locate the appropriate anchor (`<a>`) using `nextElementSibling`.

There's an added benefit that you don't need to come up with different IDs for the button and anchor elements if you have a large list (I got rid of them.)

```js
(function() {

  function generate() {
    var e, n = this.nextElementSibling,
      t = this,
      a = this.nextElementSibling.href,
      l = 10,
      d = document.createElement("span");
    n.parentNode.replaceChild(d, n), e = setInterval(function() {
      --l < 0 ? (d.parentNode.replaceChild(n, d), clearInterval(e), window.open(a), n.style.display = "inline") : (d.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-clock-o' aria-hidden='true'/> Redirecting to download page in " + l.toString() + " seconds.", t.style.display = "none")
    }, 1e3)
  }

  const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    const button = buttons[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', generate);
  }

})();
```

```css
.downloadbuttonx {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #e67e22;
  float: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}

.downloadbuttonx:hover,
.downloadingx:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #b62727;
  outline: none;
}

.batas-downx {
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
}

.background-box-st {
  background: #b62727;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  width: 310px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.background-box-n {
  background: #a30085;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  width: 310px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.file-name {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.catatan-downx {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.downloadingx {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #e67e22;
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.bungkus-info span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 80px;
  float: none;
}

.file-deskripsi {
  display: block;
}

.file-deskripsi span {
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.downloadbuttonx,
a.downloadingx {
  width: 160px;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bungkus-info span {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.file-deskripsi {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="batas-downx">
  <div class="background-box-n">
    <div class="bungkus-info">
      <div class="file-name">File 1</div>
      <button class="downloadbuttonx"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download</button>
      <a href="#" class="downloadingx" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Redirecting...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="batas-downx">
  <div class="background-box-st">
    <div class="bungkus-info">
      <div class="file-name">File 2</div>
      <button class="downloadbuttonx"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download</button>
      <a href="#" class="downloadingx" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Redirecting...</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** Re-enabled styling without using duplicate IDs by using CSS classes instead.

Comment: Hey @phuzi your solution is working fine for me but you have removed my styling that was necessary.

Comment: can you please take a moment to edit the javascript and add styling (downloadbuttonx and downloadingx)?

Comment: I can, but they aren't necessary for the question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found your mistake. It was that first Download button and the second one had the same id.
I solve by changing the second one's id.

```
function generatex() {
var e, n = document.getElementById("downloadingx"),
  t = document.getElementById("downloadbuttonx"),
  a = document.getElementById("downloadingx").href,
  l = 10,
  d = document.createElement("span");
n.parentNode.replaceChild(d, n), e = setInterval(function() {
  --l < 0 ? (d.parentNode.replaceChild(n, d), clearInterval(e), window.open(a), n.style.display = "inline") : (d.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-clock-o' aria-hidden='true'/> Redirecting to download page in " + l.toString() + " seconds.", t.style.display = "none")
}, 1e3)
}
function generatey() {
var e, n = document.getElementById("downloadingy"),
  t = document.getElementById("downloadbuttony"),
  a = document.getElementById("downloadingy").href,
  l = 10,
  d = document.createElement("span");
n.parentNode.replaceChild(d, n), e = setInterval(function() {
  --l < 0 ? (d.parentNode.replaceChild(n, d), clearInterval(e), window.open(a), n.style.display = "inline") : (d.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-clock-o' aria-hidden='true'/> Redirecting to download page in " + l.toString() + " seconds.", t.style.display = "none")
}, 1e3)
}
```

css

```
#downloadbuttonx{
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #e67e22;
  float: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}
#downloadbuttony{
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #e67e22;
  float: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}

#downloadbuttonx:hover,
#downloadingx:hover{
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #b62727;
  outline: none;
}
#downloadbuttony:hover,
#downloadingy:hover{
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #b62727;
  outline: none;
}
.batas-downx{
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display:block;
}
.batas-downy{
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display:block;
}

.background-box-st{
  background: #b62727;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  width: 310px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius:5px;
  border-top-left-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.background-box-n{
  background: #a30085;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  width: 310px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius:5px;
  border-top-left-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.file-name{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.catatan-downx{
padding:20px;
background:#f7f7f7;
color:#555;
font-size:20px;
}
.catatan-downy{
padding:20px;
background:#f7f7f7;
color:#555;
font-size:20px;
}

#downloadingx{
  display:block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #e67e22;
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  text-align:center;
  float:none;
  line-height:80px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#downloadingy{
  display:block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #e67e22;
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  text-align:center;
  float:none;
  line-height:80px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}


.bungkus-info span{
display:block;
line-height:80px;
float:none;
}

.file-deskripsi{
display:block;
}

.file-deskripsi span{
margin-right:3px;
}

#downloadbuttonx,
#downloadbuttony,
a#downloadingx,
a#downloadingy{
width:160px;
padding:15px;
cursor:pointer;
}

.bungkus-info span{
float:none;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}

.file-deskripsi{text-align:center}
}
```

html

```
<div class="batas-downx">
    <div class="background-box-n">
        <div class="bungkus-info">
            <div class="file-name">File 1</div>
            <button id="downloadbuttonx" onclick="generatex()"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download</button>
            <a href="#" id="downloadingx" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Redirecting...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="batas-downx">
    <div class="background-box-st">
        <div class="bungkus-info">
            <div class="file-name">File 1</div>
            <button id="downloadbuttony" onclick="generatey()"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download</button>
            <a href="#" id="downloadingy" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Redirecting...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add class like downloadBtn so that you can reduce css code. I am sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You are welcome. In stackoverflow, everyone helps others. I know little, but I will help others by my knowledge.

Comment: There are much better ways than duplicating code like this.

Comment: Of course you can. I think css and js codes can be reduced like defining classes.

Comment: Hey @George, Your solution was straightforward but you are duplicating the javascript, which increases the size of javascript. Is any better way? Because if I have to add the 3rd button, I have to add the Javascript of that button too along with the HTML.